# How do I apply phase center corrections to IGS satellite positions?

Tags: gps, calculate-values

I'm trying to use the International GNSS Service's SP3 precise orbit files (found [here](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/GNSS/orbit_products.html)) to calculate the position of GPS satellites for a Precise Point Positioning solution.

It appears that they're given relative to the satellite's center of mass, though, and not to the actual antenna, which is what I need to get a precise solution. The website refers me to a paper by [Montenbruck, et. al., (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280303726_GNSS_satellite_geometry_and_attitude_models) that gives a lot of information about body frames and such, but I can't make much sense of it.

Is there a simple, concise way to get the position of a GPS satellite's antenna, such that I can use it in a Precise Point Positioning solution, in ECEF coordinates, at a given point in time? I have the necessary SP3 files and the IGS's [.ATX](ftp://ftp.igs.org/pub/station/general/igs14.atx) file to get the antenna offsets relative to the satellite's body frame.